How do I drill a hole in a brass register vent cover?
I recently bought a register vent cover, and it didn't come with pre-drilled holes. I'd like to see if I can just drill the holes myself. The product page says it's made of brass, and I've heard that you need a specific drill bit for brass. Do you know where I can find those kinds of drill bits? Thank you in advance!

These are not really meant to have holes drilled in them.  Are you sure you need the holes?

Why do you need holes? If it's really made of brass, it's probably not a good idea to hang it from the ceiling unless you've designed this whole installation from scratch with suitable framing above. In which case you wouldn't be stuck now with the wrong cover. :)

Any metal bit will do. The trick is to use a center punch ($4 tool) an then some cooling fluid while drilling. WD-40 works as cooling fluid.
